# Question about 'or' and 'and' operators in R?

Tags: r

I have a general question about the ***or*** and ***and*** operators in R.

In the below example, I am assigning a value to 2 variables `x` and `y` and Im just doing some logical operations on them. But when I wrap the expression in parenthesis, the result changes... and I'm wondering why or what is the logic behind this? For example:

```
x = 10
y = 2

# x or y is equal to 2
>x|y == 2
[1] TRUE
```

But when I add parenthesis:

```
> (x|y) == 2 
[1] FALSE
```

Additionally, if I just check the `x`:

```
> x|x == 2
[1] TRUE
> (x|x) == 2 
[1] FALSE
```

Similarily for `&`:

```
> x&y == 2
[1] TRUE
> (x&y)==2
[1] FALSE
```

I know this might be a basic question, but the logic behind this isn't as intuitive as I originally thought! I know there are lots of resources online talking about these operators.. but none of them seem to answer this type of question directly.
I was wondering what is exactly going on here?

Comment: Aren't you comparing `TRUE == 2` i.e. `> x|y#
[1] TRUE` `|` returns TRUE if any of the values in 'x', 'y' are non-zero, whereas `&` returns only TRUE when both are not 0.  Also, there is precedence of operators if it is not enclosed within brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason relates to conversion of non-zero values to TRUE and zero to FALSE

```
> as.logical(x)
[1] TRUE
> as.logical(0)
[1] FALSE
```

When we use `|` (OR), it checks whether any of the elements are non-zero, and thus returns TRUE, whereas in `&`, both elements should be non-zero

```
> x|y
[1] TRUE
```

and when we compare with `2`, it is not equal because the lhs is logical, when coerced to 1 (binary values correspond to TRUE/FALSE for 1/0), and rhs is 2

```
> (x|y) == 2 
[1] FALSE
> (x|y) == 1
[1] TRUE
```

In addition, there is operator precedence when we don't wrap them inside brackets

```
x&(y == 2)
[1] TRUE
```

It returns TRUE because `x` is non zero, and `y ==2` returns TRUE, thus both returns TRUE

```
> y==2
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This makes sense to me. Thanks for explaining it!